# Is the Home Interface mandatory?

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb

I am a .NET Developer learning Java and J2EE in my spare time.  I understand that the Home Interface is used for lifecycle methods.

All the examples I look at do not have a home interface.  For example, this one: https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/entappclient.html and event this CRUD type example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_zW27Y2boCo

The two examples above work on my development PC, however there is no Home Interface.  Why is there no Home Interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Annotation have meaning too.the reason mentioned page didnot use `@Remote` a.k.a Home interface is that client is inside the JVM, code are written in Java.

**When to use**

`@Remote` annotation is provide by RMI `Remote Method Invocation`.use it, if ejb need to access the client from .Net, php application (applicable for a session bean interface or the bean implementation class itself.
It makes the session bean available to clients outside the JVM in which it is deployed). if there is no annotation in interface it will `@Local` a.k.a LocalHome  by default.

[EJB - Home/Remote and LocalHome/Local interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913267/ejb-home-remote-and-localhome-local-interfaces?rq=1)

Comment: Is there a difference between the remote interface and home interface? Are they the same thing?

Comment: they are same Home interface are represent by Remote annotation @w001977